# How to remove space between collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I have 3 cells, first cell has **label**, second cell has **textfield**, and the last cell has **button**, by using this it give automatic size but how to remove space between cells

```
if let flowlayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowlayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
        }
```

or how to use this method in my scenario

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    code
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use the following collection view delegate functions:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { 
    return 0 
}
```

And for spacing to the sides:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex UICollectionViewLayout,  section: Int) -> CGFloat {
  return 0 
}
```

**Swift 4 & 5**

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Also check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout)

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an init function for your controller, you can avoid bulking it with the **minimumLineSpacing** & **minimumInteritemSpacing** methods and do the following:

```
init() {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    
    super.init(collectionViewLayout: layout)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0 // The minimum spacing to use between items in the same row.
myCollectionView.layout = layout // or myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout ( I don't have compiler here so I do not know the property name, but I know it has property that has layout in its name )
```

Comment: @Salman500 If the item size holds the same size as the intristic content size of the cells, my answer should work. Make sure the cells size are equal to the intristic content size

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0**

There are 2 delegate method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to remove space between item and section.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```